# Не появляется иконка приложения после сборки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ресурсы, иконки

Пытаюсь добавить иконку к приложению MS Visual Studio 2008 на С++. Делаю так:

1. Клик по проекту правой кнопкой
2. Add
3. Resource
4. Icon
5. Import...
6. Выбираю картинку png
7. Нажимаю Открыть
8. Правой кнопкой по проекту
9. Build

Собирается успешно. Ничего не меняется. Как была стандартная иконка, так и остаётся. В гугле все как один пишут, что после этих шагов иконка тут же должна поменяться.

Вопрос: как добавить к приложению иконку так, чтобы её стало видно не только в обозревателе решений, но ещё и там, где она должна быть видна (на значке приложения)?

Comment: (1) Отконвертируйте картинтку в формат *.ico  (png не будет работать.) (2) resource id  для нее установить равным 1 (3) убедиться что смотрим именно на тот *.exe, который собирали. (проверить дату изменения файла).

Comment: @Chorkov, благодарю, первый совет помог. Вынесите в ответ, если хотите.